# How to inject the result of an IO action into a non-IO monadic computation

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a small bit of an architectural problem for which I'd like to see if there's a common pattern or abstraction that can help me. I'm [writing a game engine](http://www.github.com/Mokosha/Lambency) where the user is able to specify a game loop as a monadic computation of the form:

```
gameLoop :: TimeStep -> a -> Game a
```

where the `Game` monad has a bunch of access points for drawing, transforming, and interfacing with the engine in general. Then, I also provide a function that the user calls to run the simulation

```
runGame :: (TimeStep -> a -> Game a) -> a -> IO a
```

One of the main design goals of the library was to not make `Game` an instance of the `MonadIO` typeclass. This is to prevent the user from shooting themselves in the foot by changing the state of the underlying graphics calls, or loading things when they're not expected. However, there are often use cases where the result of an `IO a` is useful after the game loop has already begun. In particular, spawning enemies with procedurally generated graphical elements comes to mind.

As a result, I'd like to allow the user to request resources using something similar to the following interface:

```
data ResourceRequestResult a
  = NotLoaded
  | Loaded a

newtype ResourceRequest a = ResourceRequest {
  getRequestResult :: Game (ResourceRequestResult a)
}

requestResource :: IO a -> Game (ResourceRequest a)
```

With this, I'd like to fork a thread to load the resource and pass the result to the context of the `Game` monad and back to the user. The main goal would be that I get to decide when the IO action takes place -- somewhere that I expect it to rather than in the middle of the game loop.

One idea that I had in mind was to place another user-defined monad transformer on top of the `Game` monad... something like

```
newtype ResourceT r m a = ResourceT (StateT [ResourceRequest r] m a)
```

However, I believe that then specifying things in terms of `f :: ResourceT r Game a` becomes an API nightmare, as I'd have to support any possible combination of monad transformer stacks. Ideally I'd also like to avoid making `Game` polymorphic in `r`, as it would increase the verbosity and portability of the underlying `Game` functions as well.

Does Haskell have any abstractions or idioms for something like this programming pattern? Is what I want not possible?

Comment: For context, the current `Game` is a stack of `StateT` or `RWST` transformers with `Identity` at the bottom. It's essentially `type Game = StateT InputState (RWST Config [OutputAction] GameState Identity)`

Comment: You can [purify any IO interface](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html) mechanically.

Comment: You can include `IO` in your monad transformer stack without making your stack an instance of `MonadIO`. Then the fact that `IO` is used is just an implementation detail that you are hiding from the user.

Comment: @DanielWagner Not having an instance of `MonadIO` doesn't stop someone from writing `lift . lift ...`. One easy way to hide IO is to use a rank 2 type like `runGame :: (forall m. Monad m => GameT m a) -> IO a`. I'm doing something similar (except with typeclasses) for an answer.

Comment: @Cirdec You certainly can stop somebody from doing that, simply by virtue of the fact that `newtype Game a = Game (StateT InputState IO a)` is not a monad transformer at all.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm a little ashamed I didn't realize that sooner. Feel free to add that to the answers pile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest thing is to use module-level encapsulation. Something like this:

```
module Game (Game, loadResource) where

data GameState -- = ...
newtype Game = Game { runGame :: StateT GameState IO a }

io :: IO a -> Game a
io = Game . liftIO

loadResource :: IO a -> Game (Game a)
loadResource action = io $ do
    v <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO (action >>= putMVar v)
    return . io $ takeMVar v
```

As seen here, you can use the fact that `Game` can do `IO` within the `Game` module without exposing this fact to the rest of the world, exposing only the bits of `IO` that you consider "safe". In particular, you would not make `Game` an instance of `MonadIO` (and it can't be made an instance of `MonadTrans` as it has the wrong kind). Moreover, the `io` function and `Game` constructor are not exported, so the user can't pull an end-run in that way.

Answer (score 7):

Monads and especially monad transformers [come from trying to build complicated programs out of simpler pieces](http://haskell.cs.yale.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/POPL96-Modular-interpreters.pdf). An additional transformer for the new responsibility is an idiomatic way of handling this problem in Haskell.

There's more than one way to deal with transformer stacks. Since you are already using [mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) in your code, I'll assume you are comfortable with the choice of typeclasses for penetrating the transformer stack.

The examples given below are complete overkill for the toy problem. This whole example is huge - it shows how pieces can come together from monads defined in multiple different ways - in terms of IO, in terms of a transformer like `RWST` and in terms of free monad from a functor.

#### An interface

I like complete examples, so we'll start with a complete interface for a game engine. This will be a small collection of typeclasses each representing one responsibility of the game engine. The ultimate goal will be to provide a function with the following type

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

runGame :: (forall m. MonadGame m => m a) -> IO a
```

As long as `MonadGame` doesn't include `MonadIO` a user of `runGame` can't make use of `IO` in general. We can still export all of our underlying types and write instances like `MonadIO` and a user of the library can still be sure they didn't make a mistake as long as they enter the library through `runGame`. The typeclasses presented here are actually the [same as a free monad, and you don't have to choose between them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767740/414413).

If you don't like either the rank 2 type or a free monad for some reason, you can instead make a new type with no `MonadIO` instance and not export the constructor as in [Daniel Wagner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393837/414413).

Our interface will consist of four type classes - `MonadGameState` for handling state, `MonadGameResource` for handling resources, `MonadGameDraw` for drawing, and an overarching `MonadGame` that includes all the other three for convenience.

The `MonadGameState` is a simpler version of `MonadRWS` from `Control.Monad.RWS.Class`. The only reason to define our own class is so that `MonadRWS` is still available for someone else to use. `MonadGameState` needs data types for the games configuration, how it outputs data to draw, and the state maintained.

```
import Data.Monoid

data GameConfig = GameConfig

newtype GameOutput = GameOutput (String -> String)
instance Monoid GameOutput where
    mempty = GameOutput id
    mappend (GameOutput a) (GameOutput b) = GameOutput (a . b)

data GameState = GameState {keys :: Maybe String}

class Monad m => MonadGameState m where
    getConfig :: m GameConfig
    output    :: GameOutput -> m ()
    getState  :: m GameState
    updateState :: (GameState -> (a, GameState)) -> m a
```

Resources are handled by returning an action that can be run later to get the resource if it was loaded.

```
class (Monad m) => MonadGameResource m where
    requestResource :: IO a -> m (m (Maybe a))
```

I'm going to add another concern to the game engine and eliminate the need for a `(TimeStep -> a -> Game a)`. Instead of drawing by returning a value, my interface will draw by asking for it explicitly. The return of `draw` will tell us the `TimeStep`.

```
data TimeStep = TimeStep

class Monad m => MonadGameDraw m where
    draw :: m TimeStep
```

Finally, `MonadGame` will require instances for the other three type classes.

```
class (MonadGameState m, MonadGameDraw m, MonadGameResource m) => MonadGame m
```

#### Default definitions for transformers

It's easy to provide default definition of all four type classes for [monad transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html). We'll add `default`s to all three classes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class Monad m => MonadGameState m where
    getConfig :: m GameConfig
    output    :: GameOutput -> m ()
    getState  :: m GameState
    updateState :: (GameState -> (a, GameState)) -> m a

    default getConfig :: (MonadTrans t, MonadGameState m) => t m GameConfig
    getConfig = lift getConfig

    default output :: (MonadTrans t, MonadGameState m) => GameOutput -> t m ()
    output = lift . output

    default getState :: (MonadTrans t, MonadGameState m) => t m GameState
    getState = lift getState

    default updateState :: (MonadTrans t, MonadGameState m) => (GameState -> (a, GameState)) -> t m a
    updateState = lift . updateState

class (Monad m) => MonadGameResource m where
    requestResource :: IO a -> m (m (Maybe a))

    default requestResource :: (Monad m, MonadTrans t, MonadGameResource m) => IO a -> t m (t m (Maybe a))
    requestResource = lift . liftM lift . requestResource
class Monad m => MonadGameDraw m where
    draw :: m TimeStep

    default draw :: (MonadTrans t, MonadGameDraw m) => t m TimeStep
    draw = lift draw
```

I know that I plan on using `RWST` for state, `IdentityT` for resources, and `FreeT` for drawing, so we'll provide instances for all of those transformers now.

```
import Control.Monad.RWS.Lazy
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free
import Control.Monad.Trans.Identity

instance (Monoid w, MonadGameState m) => MonadGameState (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, MonadGameDraw m) => MonadGameDraw (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, MonadGameResource m) => MonadGameResource (RWST r w s m)
instance (Monoid w, MonadGame m) => MonadGame (RWST r w s m)

instance (Functor f, MonadGameState m) => MonadGameState (FreeT f m)
instance (Functor f, MonadGameDraw m) => MonadGameDraw (FreeT f m)
instance (Functor f, MonadGameResource m) => MonadGameResource (FreeT f m)
instance (Functor f, MonadGame m) => MonadGame (FreeT f m)

instance (MonadGameState m) => MonadGameState (IdentityT m)
instance (MonadGameDraw m) => MonadGameDraw (IdentityT m)
instance (MonadGameResource m) => MonadGameResource (IdentityT m)
instance (MonadGame m) => MonadGame (IdentityT m)
```

#### Game state

We plan on building the game state from `RWST`, so we'll make `GameT` a `newtype` for `RWST`. This allows us to attach our own instances like `MonadGameState`. We'll derive as many classes as we can with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

-- Monad typeclasses from base
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Fix
-- Monad typeclasses from transformers
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
-- Monad typeclasses from mtl
import Control.Monad.Error.Class
import Control.Monad.Cont.Class

newtype GameT m a = GameT {getGameT :: RWST GameConfig GameOutput GameState m a}
    deriving (Alternative, Monad, Functor, MonadFix, MonadPlus, Applicative,
              MonadTrans, MonadIO,
              MonadError e, MonadCont,
              MonadGameDraw)
```

We'll also provide the underivable instance for `MonadGameResource` and a convenience function equivalent to `runRWST`

```
instance (MonadGameResource m) => MonadGameResource (GameT m)

runGameT :: GameT m a -> GameConfig -> GameState -> m (a, GameState, GameOutput)
runGameT = runRWST . getGameT
```

This lets us get to the meat of providing `MonadGameState` which just passes everything off onto `RWST`.

```
instance (Monad m) => MonadGameState (GameT m) where
    getConfig   = GameT ask
    output      = GameT . tell
    getState    = GameT get
    updateState = GameT . state
```

If we just added `MonadGameState` to something that already provided support for resources and drawing we just made a `MonadGame`.

```
instance (MonadGameDraw m, MonadGameResource m) => MonadGame (GameT m)
```

#### Resource handling

We can handle resources with `IO` and `MVar`s as in [jcast's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27391422/414413). We'll make a transformer just so we have a type to attach an instance for `MonadGameResource` to. This is total overkill. To add overkill to overkill, I'm going to `newType` `IdentityT` just to get its `MonadTrans` instance. We'll derive everything we can.

```
newtype GameResourceT m a = GameResourceT {getGameResourceT :: IdentityT m a}
    deriving (Alternative, Monad, Functor, MonadFix, Applicative,
              MonadTrans, MonadIO,
              MonadError e, MonadReader r, MonadState s, MonadWriter w, MonadCont,
              MonadGameState, MonadGameDraw) 

runGameResourceT :: GameResourceT m a -> m a
runGameResourceT = runIdentityT . getGameResourceT
```

We'll add an instance for `MonadGameResource`. This is exactly the same as the other answers.

```
gameResourceIO :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> GameResourceT m a
gameResourceIO = GameResourceT . IdentityT . liftIO

instance (MonadIO m) => MonadGameResource (GameResourceT m) where
    requestResource a = gameResourceIO $ do
        var <- newEmptyMVar
        forkIO (a >>= putMVar var)
        return (gameResourceIO . tryTakeMVar $ var)
```

If we just added resource handling to something that already supported drawing and state, we have a `MonadGame`

```
instance (MonadGameState m, MonadGameDraw m, MonadIO m) => MonadGame (GameResourceT m)
```

#### Drawing

Like Gabriel Gonzales pointed out, "You can [purify any IO interface mechanically](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/purify-code-using-free-monads.html)". We'll use this trick to implement `MonadGameDraw`. The only drawing operation is to `Draw` with a function from the `TimeStep` to what to do next.

```
newtype DrawF next = Draw (TimeStep -> next)
    deriving (Functor)
```

Combined with the free monad transformer, this is the trick I'm using to eliminate the need for a `(TimeStep -> a -> Game a)`. Our `DrawT` transformer that adds drawing responsibility to a monad with `FreeT DrawF`.

```
newtype DrawT m a = DrawT {getDrawT :: FreeT DrawF m a}
    deriving (Alternative, Monad, Functor, MonadPlus, Applicative,
              MonadTrans, MonadIO,
              MonadError e, MonadReader r, MonadState s, MonadWriter w, MonadCont,
              MonadFree DrawF,
              MonadGameState)
```

Once again we'll define the default instance for `MonadGameResource` and another convenience function.

```
instance (MonadGameResource m) => MonadGameResource (DrawT m)

runDrawT :: DrawT m a -> m (FreeF DrawF a (FreeT DrawF m a))
runDrawT = runFreeT . getDrawT
```

The `MonadGameDraw` instance says we need to `Free (Draw next)` where the `next` thing to do is `return` the `TimeStamp`.

```
instance (Monad m) => MonadGameDraw (DrawT m) where
    draw = DrawT . FreeT . return . Free . Draw $ return
```

If we just added drawing to something that already handles state and resources, we have a `MonadGame`

```
instance (MonadGameState m, MonadGameResource m) => MonadGame (DrawT m)
```

#### The game engine

Drawing and the game state interact with each other - when we draw we need to get the output from the `RWST` to know what to draw. This is easy to do if `GameT` is directly under `DrawT`. Our toy loop is very simple; it draws the output and reads lines from the input.

```
runDrawIO :: (MonadIO m) => GameConfig -> GameState -> DrawT (GameT m) a -> m a
runDrawIO cfg s x = do
    (f, s, GameOutput w) <- runGameT (runDrawT x) cfg s 
    case f of 
        Pure a -> return a
        Free (Draw f) -> do
            liftIO . putStr . w $ []
            keys <- liftIO getLine
            runDrawIO cfg (GameState (Just keys)) (DrawT . f $ TimeStep)
```

From this we can define running a game in `IO` by adding `GameResourceT`.

```
runGameIO :: DrawT (GameT (GameResourceT IO)) a -> IO a
runGameIO = runGameResourceT . runDrawIO GameConfig (GameState Nothing)
```

Finally, we can write `runGame` with the signature we've wanted from the beginning.

```
runGame :: (forall m. MonadGame m => m a) -> IO a
runGame x = runGameIO x
```

#### Example

This example requests the reverse of the last input after 5 seconds and displays everything that has data available each frame.

```
example :: MonadGame m => m ()
example = go []
    where
        go handles = do
            handles <- dump handles
            state <- getState
            handles <- case keys state of
                Nothing -> return handles
                Just x  -> do
                    handle <- requestResource ((threadDelay 5000000 >>) . return . reverse $ x)
                    return ((x,handle):handles)
            draw
            go handles
        dump [] = return []
        dump ((name, handle):xs) = do
            resource <- handle
            case resource of
                Nothing -> liftM ((name,handle):) $ dump xs
                Just contents -> do
                    output . GameOutput $ (name ++) . ("\n" ++) . (contents ++) . ("\n" ++)
                    dump xs

main = runGameIO example
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look up `MVar`s: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html.

```
tryReadMVar :: MVar a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

gives you your `ResourceRequest`, and

```
putMVar :: MVar a -> a -> IO ()
```

can be used to press the result at the end of the thread.  Something like (ignoring newtypes etc.):

```
requestResourceImpl :: IO a -> IO (IO (Maybe a))
requestResourceImpl a = do
    mv <- newEmptyMVar
    forkIO $ do
        x <- a
        putMVar mv x
    return $ tryReadMVar mv
```

This doesn't handle cases where `a` throws exceptions etc; if `a` does throw an exception, your resulting `ResourceRequest` will simply never report the resource as being available.

I strongly recommend making `GameMonad` an abstract type.  You can make it a `newtype` (you can add `deriving MonadReader` etc. if necessary).  Then you don't export its constructor; instead, define abstract operations like `requestResource` and export them instead.

Comment: Generating a value of type `ResourceRequest a` is straightforward, as you've shown in your post. I'd like to know what the `Game (ResourceRequest a)` computation would look like without making `Game` an instance of `MonadIO`. Do I need to make `Game` some special kind of monad in order to support things like this?

Comment: @Mokosha, yes you need to replace `GameMonad` with