# How to assign a value from the IO monad to a RankNType qualified constructor

Tags: haskell, free-monad, higher-rank-types

**(UPDATED)**

I have made an interface using a [Free Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767740/163177) to a generic data store. I want to place the specific interpreter (:: DataStore a -> IO a) chosen by the user at run time into a state monad along with some other information.  I cannot seem to put anything into this field in the data structure.

How do I put a value into a field defined as a higher rank type?

Below is a minimum example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, DeriveFunctor #-}

data ProgramState = PS { -- line 3
    [...]
  , storageInterface :: (forall a. DataStore a -> IO a)
  }

data DataStoreF next = 
     Create    Asset                           ( String -> next)
  |  Read      String                          ( Asset  -> next)
  |  Update    Asset                           ( Bool   -> next)
  |  UpdateAll [Asset]                         ( Bool   -> next)
  |  [...]
  deriving Functor

type DataStore = Free DataStoreF

runMemory :: (IORef (Map String Asset)) -> DataStore a -> IO a
runMemory ms (Pure a) = return a
runMemory ms (Free Create asset next) = [...]
runMemory ms (Free Read   str   next) = [...]
[...]

pickStorageInterface :: IO (DataStore a -> IO a)
pickStorageInterface = do
  opts <- parseOptions
  case (storage opts) of
     MemoryStorage -> 
       ms <- readAssetsFromDisk 
       return $ runMemory ms
     SomeOtherStorage -> [...]

restOfProgram :: StateT ProgramState IO
restOfProgram = [...]

main = do
  si <- pickStorageInterface
  let programState = PS { storageInterface = si} -- line 21
  evalState restOfProgram programState
```

When I try to do this GHC complains that:

```
Main.hs: << Line 21 >>
Couldn't match type `a0' with `a'
  because type variable `a' would escape its scope
This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
  a type expected by the context: DataStore a -> IO a
  at Main.hs <<line 3>>
Expected type: DataStore a -> IO a
  Actual type: DataStore a0 -> IO a0
In the `storageInterface' field of a record
  [...]
```

---

**UPDATE**

My original minimal example was to minimal.  Some further experimentation shows that the problem arises when I need to load the interface in an the IO monad so I can read the command line options.  I've updated the example to include that issue.  Knowing this I may be able to code around it.

Interesting GHCI tells me that the results of a function of type `IO (DataStore a -> IO a)` is `DataStore GHC.Prim.Any -> IO GHC.Prim.Any` which is not what I expected.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but why don't you just do `data ProgramState a = PS { ... , storageInterface :: DataStore a -> IO a }`? I don't think that breaks any of the code you've pasted here...

Comment: Can't replicate the issue.

Comment: Alec ` Not in scope: type variable 'a' `

Comment: Did you include the type variable `data ProgramState **a** = ..`?

Comment: No, I use RankNTypes.  If I didn't I would need to existentially quantify the StateT monad it goes into so and I just kick the can down the road.

Comment: I'm really confused now. `evalState` expects a `StateT` as its first argument not a `ProgramState`. Did you mean `evalState restOfProgram programState `? There really isn't enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: Yep I got the args backwards.  fixed

Comment: Could you post `restOfProgram` then? That will almost certainly expose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that

```
pickStorageInterface :: forall a. IO (DataStore a -> IO a)
```

while we would need the (impredicative) type

```
pickStorageInterface :: IO (forall a. DataStore a -> IO a)
```

for the code above to work. Alas, the impredicative types are in a sad state now in GHC, and are best to be avoided.

You can work around that using a `newtype` wrapper around the universally quantified type:

```
newtype SI = SI { runSI :: forall a. DataStore a -> IO a }

pickStorageInterface :: IO SI
pickStorageInterface = do
  opts <- parseOptions
  case (storage opts) of
     MemoryStorage -> 
       ms <- readAssetsFromDisk 
       return $ SI $ runMemory ms
     ...

main = do
  si <- pickStorageInterface
  let programState = PS { storageInterface = runSI si}
  ...
```