# Why does the type of a function change when it comes out of a monad in GHCi

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghc, ghci

Something changes about the type of a function when it comes out of a monad.

In GHCI:

```
> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
> a <- return map
> :t a
a :: (GHC.Prim.Any -> GHC.Prim.Any)
 -> [GHC.Prim.Any] -> [GHC.Prim.Any]
```

This change makes it hard to store the function in a higher rank type.

What is happening here and can I make it not happen?

(Also doesn't this violate one of the monad laws?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is weird `ghci` behavior. Something like `λ> do a <- return map; return (a (+ 1) [1,2,3])` works as you'd expect.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, there is no point in doing anything like `a <- return map` - its the same as `let a = map`, which works just fine. That said, I don't think that is your question...

---

Checking out the documentation of [`GHC.Prim.Any`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.4.0.0/candidate/docs/GHC-Prim.html) which gives us a big hint as to the role of `Any`.

> It's also used to instantiate un-constrained type variables after type
>   checking. For example, `length` has type
>
> ```
> length :: forall a. [a] -> Int
> ```
>
> and the list datacon for the empty list has type
>
> ```
> [] :: forall a. [a]
> ```
>
> In order to compose these two terms as `length []` a
>   type application is required, but there is no constraint on the
>   choice. In this situation GHC uses `Any`

(In terms of type application syntax, that looks like `length @Any ([] @Any *)`)

The problem is that when GHCi sees `x <- return map` it tries to desugar it to `return map >>= \x -> ...` but the `...` part is whatever you enter next into GHCi. Normally it would figure out what the type variables of `map` are going to be instantiated to (or whether they even should be instantiated to anything) based the `...`, but since it has nothing there.

Another key point that @sepp2k points out is that `x` *can't be given a polymorphic type* because `(>>=)` expects (on its RHS) a rank-1 function, and that means its argument can't be polymorphic. (Loosening this condition pushes you straight into `RankNTypes` at which point you lose the ability to infer types reliably.)

Therefore, needing `x` to be monomorphic and having no information to help it instantiate the type variables that prevent `x` from being monomorphic, it defaults to using `Any`. That means that instead of `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` you get `(Any -> Any) -> [Any] -> [Any]`.

Comment: It also should be pointed out that `a` can't just be given a polymorphic type because function arguments can't be polymorphic (unless the function is a higher rank function, but `>>=` takes a rank-1 function).

Comment: @sepp2k Good point! Let me add that in.

Comment: `a <- return  map` was simply the minimum viable example.  I am actually trying to build a polymorphic function from command line options and store that function in a StateT based monad for later use. I keep getting `a` is not `a0` type errors, and I thought this might shed some light on why. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648935

Comment: @JohnF.Miller I am fully aware of this - I've also been trying to help you on that question, but you will need to post more information. But this really is a completely separate problem. Key takeaway is write `let a = ...` instead of `a <- return ...` when debugging in GHCi (for reasons just related to GHCi).