# ScopedTypeVariables and RankNTypes with GHC.TypeLits

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, forall

I'm trying to use `DataKinds` along with type-level literals to make a type safe currency conversion library. So far I have defined these data types:

```
data Currency (s :: Symbol) = Currency Double
    deriving Show

type USD = Currency "usd"
type GBP = Currency "gbp"

usd :: Double -> USD
usd = Currency

gbp :: Double -> GBP
gbp = Currency

data SProxy (s :: Symbol) = SProxy
```

Along with a function that allows me to convert between them:

```
convert :: forall a b. (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => Currency a -> Currency b
convert (Currency a) = case (symbolVal (SProxy :: SProxy a), 
                             symbolVal (SProxy :: SProxy b)) of
          ("usd", "gbp") -> Currency (a * 0.75)
          ("gbp", "usd") -> Currency (a * 1.33)
```

Here, I have used `ScopedTypeVariables` to supply the constraint `KnownSymbol a` to `symbolVal SProxy`. This works fine, however, I would like to be able to make the conversion rates update from an external source, perhaps a text file or an API such as [fixer](http://fixer.io/).

Obviously, I could just wrap the return type in `IO`, forming

```
convert :: forall a b. (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => Currency a -> IO (Currency b)
```

but I would like to be able to keep a pure API. My first thought was to have the conversion rate map be obtained using `unsafePerformIO`, but this is unsafe so I instead thought I could use another function `getConvert` with a type to the effect of

```
getConvert :: IO (forall a b. (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => Currency a -> Currency b)
```

(i.e an IO action returning a `convert` type function) so that it could be used like this:

```
do
    convert <- getConvert
    print $ convert (gbp 10) :: USD
```

However, I have been unable to get this to type check - GHC complains that it:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘forall (a :: Symbol) (b :: Symbol). 
                              (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => 
                              Currency a -> Currency b’ 
with actual type ‘Currency a0 -> Currency b0’
```

When I had GHC infer the type of `return convert`, it did not infer the type I wanted but instead moved the `forall a b` to the prenex position, which type checks, until I try to use `convert' <- getConvert`, at which point it fails saying that there is `No instance for (KnownSymbol n0)`

**My question is why does this not type check, and what would be the correct type for the function `getConvert`?**

First I thought that it may be the fact both `ScopedTypeVariables` and `RankNTypes` use the `forall` quantifier in different ways, but toggling `RankNTypes` has had no effect. I also tried moving the quantifier to the front as GHC suggested but this does not give me the rank-2 type that I need.

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38653526/3234959

Comment: By the way, have you looked at the `reflection` package? This smells like something it might be good for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImpredicativeTypes` <s>don't</s> *can't* really work right; avoid them. Instead of using `IO (forall a. b. ...)` you can wrap the exchange rate conversion table in a `data` type that preserves its polymorphic type.

```
data ExchangeRates = ExchangeRates {
    getER :: forall a b. (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => Currency a -> Currency b
}
```

and return an `IO ExchangeRates` instead

```
-- getConvert :: IO (forall a b. (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => Currency a -> Currency b)
getConvert    :: IO ExchangeRates
getConvert = return (ExchangeRates convert)
```

And use it almost as you expected. Notice the parenthesis to group the `:: USD` type signature with the converted value.

```
main = do
    convert <- getER <$> getConvert
    print $ (convert (gbp 10) :: USD)
```

Comment: IIRC, this makes `convert` monomorphic: you can't use it on both GBP and USD at the same time. To get the full polytype one needs to something like `do c <- getConvert ; let { convert :: forall ... ; convert = getEr c } ; print (convert ...)`

Comment: @chi With `NoMonomorphismRestriction` you can just do `let convert = getER c`